# Does my approach still relevant in modern PHP programming?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I am a total beginner in PHP and writes simple web apps in procedural approach to apply what I've learned so far. I place all the functions in a single php file, no classes just plain functions. DB connection settings are also in a single file. There's also no front controllers and routers. I am coding in a traditional way.

Now, I want to know your opinion about my approach. Does this apply in real world web development? If I am going to learn new techniques to improve my PHP knowledge, what are they? Thank you so much! Your suggestions will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it really depends on the complexity of your application(s). if its something simple that you make and then it's done, and you move on to the next project, it's probably a fine approach. if it's something that isn't so simple, or has the possibility of growing in scope, or it's something you continually go back to modify, it is probably not a good approach.

in the second case, you will want to look into oop and agile design principles.

Answer (score 1):

To my mind your approach is not really helpfull this days. As you can see OOP is nowdays rulez, MVC pattern rulez and so on. The main problem with such kind of a style is being very hard to support your projects.

In PHP there is a lot of cool frameworks (Symfony, Symfony2, Zend, Codeigniter and so on). Very usefull improvement in PHP 5.3 is namespaces. For example I need to function with the same relust, but different realization, due to your style I couldn't do that, cause there will be a name conflict. So tere is namespaces is very helpfull.

There is no need to sit and study PHP 5.3 cook-book. Just start with one of the framework, I am working with Symfony 1.4, it's great example of OOP, MVC and other modern tecniques. But now I would advise you a Symfony2, there is a lot of features, namespace-based, highly customizable. If you prefer such a programming style, I think you don't like to use big and fat frameworks, but in Sf2 you can enable/disable hardly everything, and more - get from the framework parts without losing functionality.

Sorry, but there is no place for procedural programming, except hi-load dev.

Hope that helps you with suggestion.